# Error not being handled in chain of promises

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new to Node and am currently trying to tweak an existing project. Part of this uses the `follow-redirects` package to make HTTP(S) requests to fetch an image.

Occasionally my service crashes with the following trace:

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: socket hang up
  at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
  at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
  at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.(anonymous function) (/home/.../node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:13:24)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
  at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
  at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:9)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
  [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I assume this means that I am dropping the error which comes back from the HTTP request.

Here is my function where I make the request:

```
function fetchRemote (imageUrl) {
  let options = ...

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(options, resolve);
  });
}
```

And it's called using a chain of promises.

```
fetchRemote(imageUrl)
  .then(getResizeStream)
  .then(storeImage)
  .then(finished)
  .catch(error);

function error (err) {
  reject(new Error(`Failed: ${err.message}`));
};
```

Is there a logic pathway I'm missing, or should this properly catch the error? Or is the issue actually in the `follow-redirects` package?

Comment: Would you please explain the following line: `reject(new Error());` where is `reject` defined?

Comment: @RafiHenig That is a response to an enclosing promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets are "event" emitter based and not promises. You need to handle errors on sockets by doing something along the lines of

```
socket.on('error',function(err){ /* handle error */});

// for you:
https
  .get(options, resolve)
  .on('error', err => {
    reject(err);
  });
```